# how to fix it Issue found: Violation of Deceptive Ads policy

Tags: android

**App Status: Rejected**
Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to the policy issue(s) listed below. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.

**Issue found: Violation of Deceptive Ads policy**
To make sure users have a positive experience on Google Play, we don’t allow apps that contain deceptive or disruptive ads. If an app contains ads that aren’t clearly labeled as ads or that simulate the user interface of any app feature, notifications, or OS warning elements, it violates our Deceptive Ads policy. For more information, watch Monetization and Ads video.

Our review found that your app doesn’t appear to comply with this policy because it contains:
Ads that aren’t clearly labeled.
Issue details

**We found an issue in the following area(s):**

SPLIT_BUNDLE 12: In-app experience: Please see attached screenshot IN_APP_EXPERIENCE-4004.png
Additionally, follow these steps to bring your app into compliance:

Remove any ads that violate the Deceptive Ads policy and address any other content in your app's store listing that doesn’t comply with this policy.
About the Deceptive Ads policy
We don’t allow apps that contain deceptive or disruptive ads.

Comment: Have you checked the image sent to you ```Please see attached screenshot IN_APP_EXPERIENCE-4004.png```??

Answer (score 0):

According to the Google Play Developer Policy Center1, deceptive ads are ads that are not clearly labeled as ads or that simulate the user interface of any app feature, notifications, or OS warning elements. For example, ads that look like buttons, menus, dialogs, or system notifications are considered deceptive. Users should be able to easily distinguish between ads and app content.

**Open Google Play Console**

App content

Data safety -> Manage

Overview click next

Answer the questions (then next):

Does your app collect or share any of the required user data types? = yes

Is all the user data collected by your app encrypted in transit? = yes

Do you provide a way for users to request that their data is deleted? = yes

go to Device or other IDs and check it then next

check Device or other IDs and manage it

answer the questions

Is this data collected, shared, or both? = Collected

Is this data processed ephemerally? = yes

Is this data required for your app, or can users choose whether it's collected? = Users can choose whether this data is collected

Why is this user data collected? = check App functionality

then save

click next and save and app will review and approved by play store team